# How to apply a texture on a 3D object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures

I've try to apply a texture (png file) to a 3d object imported in Java. 
Here is my code, i think i haven't bend it correct.

render block:

```
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()){

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT
  glPushMatrix();      
  glNewList(treeDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);

  Model m = null;
    try {
          m = OBJLoader.loadModel(new File(ObjectConstants.tree));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Display.destroy();
          System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Display.destroy();
          System.exit(1);
        }

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (Face face : m.faces) {
        Vector3f n1 = m.normals.get((int) face.normals.x - 1);
        glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);

        Vector3f v1 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.x - 1);
        glTexCoord3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
        glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);

        Vector3f v2 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.y - 1);
        glTexCoord3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
        glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);

        Vector3f v3 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.z - 1);
        glTexCoord3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
        glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
    }

    glEnd();
    glEndList();

    glPopMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    Display.update();
    Display.sync(60);
  }
```

where ,

```
vertex=new Vector3f(); //three indices, not vector
normals= new Vector3f();
```

after using this piece of code i obtain only half of object rendered

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using both vertex coordinates and normal vectors as texture coordinates. Neither one are really suitable as texture coordinates, but I don't see how using a mix of both makes sense. You're also specifying texture coordinates twice before specifying a vertex.

Comment: I see you'r point of view, but i asume that if in a 2D object if i apply texture on it using its vetrtexte (and it woked nicely) , in 3D it is the same. But if you have other sugestion I am opened to it.

Comment: Not sure if it will give very nice results, but it should certainly work if you consistently use the vertex coordinates. Your code just looks very confusing since you're using the normal vector values in some of your `glTexCoord3f()` calls, and the vertex coordinates in others. If you stick with the vertex coordinates, you should make sure that the texture wrap modes are set to `GL_REPEAT`, unless all your coordinates are between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: I've checked the coordonates and all of them are betwin 0.0 and 1.0, if i use make them negative the other side of my tree renders.I think this is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the n texture coordinates with the v texture coordinates. Does the other side of the tree render? Is it the same? I am thinking that you are using only half the texture coordinates on the normals and half on the vertices.

Comment: I've done as you sugested but still it's render only half a tree.

Comment: I can see at the bottom that it says Image Width 768. Texture Width 1024. This could be your problem. Try using a different image that is 1024 x 512.